# Add tomcat9 to Eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat9

I want to add tomcat 9 to eclipse neon, I go to `preferences/Server/Runtime environments/` to add tomcat 9, but there is no `apache tomcat 9` to select, the highest selection item is `apache tomcat 7`, so How to add tomcat 9 to eclipse neon? the eclipse is the newest version, and my computer is Mac os 10.13.

Answer (score 0):

I have even tried to add Tomcat 9 in Eclipse Neon and Luna, and guess what happened, I was getting many errors. So, what is I did I **downloaded Eclipse Oxygen** and Import all my projects to oxygen. And added Tomcat 9 to "Oxygen" its working fine. The thing is that you need to upgrade the editor. Eclipse has nothing to do with your OS.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I have to use tomcat 7 now.